# Can output be written without sending headers (For debugging)

Tags: php, header, output

I have a php server script that loops through session id's, and checks their values, and I'd like to output text for debugging reasons, but I get the 'Headers already sent' error (Which is expected) ... So I was wondering if there was a way to output text without sending headers ... This may be the stupidest question I've ever asked, but hey Lol

Comment: post some code, anyway ob_starts will make the job: http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.ob-start.php

Comment: Could you also this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php

Comment: @Bugs `error_log` does not prevent `Headers already sent` error

Comment: @GuneyOzsan I definitely wasn't clear there. My suggestion was to write logs to a file rather than sending them to the browser, which would make sending any debugging text to the browser unnecessary and therefore indirectly resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `ob_start` function, which starts output buffering and which will result in the `header` function not throwing the error message.

You could also use a file (`file_put_contents`).

Or like Collin Grady said: If it's just for debugging, ignore the warnings, read the information you need and remove the debug prints again.

Comment: file_put_contents works a treat :D ... I probably didn't mention, that I needed the script to continue running (It's an infinite loop script) ...

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that error because you're sending a header later in the file. If you only need the debugging info and don't care about the rest of the script running, just `exit;` after you print your debug info; this will terminate the script right there, allowing you to see the debug info without your later `header()` calls triggering an error.

Answer (score 1):

`ob_start()` will be helpful.

You can also check this http://phpdebugbar.com/ generally for debug :-)